# Webhook discord bug roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

i have this scripts error below:
attempt to call a boolean value
attempt to call a number value

Here is the script :

```lua
--Game Info
local SystemName = "TestSystemname"
local WhitelistedServ = false
local OwnerId = game.CreatorId
local GameId = game.GameId
local MaxPlayers = game.Players.MaxPlayers
local GameUrl = "https://www.roblox.com/games/"..GameId

--Webhook sender and message creator in JS
local WebhookUrlServ = ""
local MessageDataServ = {["content"] = "New game started with the whitelist system !"..SystemName
    "The Owner Id= "..OwnerId
    "Is Game whitelisted ? "..WhitelistedServ
    "How Many Players Max? "..MaxPlayers
    "The Game Url= "..GameUrl}
MessageDataServ = HttpServ:JSONEncode(MessageDataServ)
```

Thanks,

Comment: There should be commas between items in a table constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, i tryed to send a value i just need replace this

```
local WhitelistedServ = false
by this
local WhitelistedServ = "false"
```

and it will be work, value cant be in this script for some reason and make with embed is better.